# Jquery Multiple Dynamic Accordion Creation

Tags: jquery-ui, dynamic-programming, jquery-ui-accordion

I am creating multiple jquery ui accordions dynamically on a page.

The render of the page takes a realllly long time and it gets stuck on the creations of the accordions.

Is there a way to create multiple accordions on the same moment?

Thank you

EDIT

Think I have a few hundered h3 & divs on my screen and on load of the page i call this function:

```
function createAccordion(accordion) {
    if (typeof accordion == 'undefined')
         accordion = '.accordion';

    $(accordion).accordion({
        active: false,
        collapsible: true,
        animate:false,
        heightStyle: 'content'
    });
}
```

Comment: `without code === no help` !! share your codes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try using `Html5` web workers.  This is designed to free up the UI thread when doing large amounts of processing.  See example on [w3c schools](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_webworkers.asp)

Alternatively you might want to look at `setTimeout` patterns.  A good example [here](http://fitzgeraldnick.com/weblog/35/).

Comment: how would that create my accordions faster?

Comment: "The render of the page takes a realllly long time and it gets stuck on the creations of the accordions." - the UI thread on the client can only do one thing at a time and that's why it seems to gets stuck.

Comment: ok, so would you suggest the webworkers? how should I implement it? Never worked with it before, any tips?

Comment: I wouldn't take too long to give it a whirl.  Try and move your creational code to that thread.  It may not be supported on older browsers though so you need to consider that.